# Drupal db_select + Index Hints in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, drupal, indexing

In Drupal 7, when using db_select, does anyone know if there is a way to specify MySQL's USE INDEX syntax, to hint what index the query should use?

As seen here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/index-hints.html

Answer (score 1):

There does not appear to be any native method for doing so. If it is critical to your site, you could always extend the [SelectQueryExtender](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!select.inc/class/SelectQueryExtender/7) class and write your own.

Comment: I had a hunch this was a bit obscure for Drupal. Maybe I'll lok into the QueryExtender. Thanks for the heads up.